# Estoy consultando un WSDL por android utilizando ksoap2, y siembre me sale el error Unmarsshalling Error:unexpected element

Tags: android, android-studio, ksoap

Estoy consultando un WSDL por android utilizando ksoap2, y siembre me sale el error Unmarsshalling Error:unexpected element[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Michael. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, _debería_ dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayúdanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto; no explica qué se está haciendo ni nada que nos de alguna pista de __dónde__ sale el error. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo más de información, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un __[mcve]__ en todas las preguntas.

Comment: pon el metodo que utilizas para para ver como esta construido el cuerpo de tu Soap, y que version del Ksoap utilizas de esta libreria